Ingress nginx routes to last wildcard and ignores precedence
I have the following ingress service config:
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-svc
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
    - host: localhost
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /backend
            backend:
              service:
                name: backend-svc
                port:
                  number: 4000
            pathType: Prefix
          - path: /?(.*)
            backend:
              service:
                name: web-svc
                port:
                  number: 8080
            pathType: Prefix

and I forward the port so I can access the cluster through localhost:3000, but it looks like when I try to access localhost:3000/backend, I routed to the web-svc and get a 404 status code and not routed to the backend-svc as expected. When I remove the reference to the web-svc, though, I'm able to be routed to the backend service just fine. I had also tried to play with different path types other than Prefix like ImplementationSpecific and Fixed but they made things worse. From my understanding, this is a fairly common use case where I expose a client service and How do I fix this? Thanks.
